# Calling another method within method with the same name in Java

Tags: java, android, methods

I am trying to call method which I have created long before I found out that interface I am using for another stuff need me to call its predefined method, which is the same name of the method I want to call inside.
Example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //doSomething
}
public void method() {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //here I want to call the top onClick method
        }
    });
}
```

Are you guys able to help me how can I use the top method, not recursively the inside one?
Thx in advance.
JF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
<enclosing-class>.this.onClick();
```

so if you're say in `MainActivity`, then:

```
MainActivity.this.onClick();
```

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a milion.

Comment: Happy to help! Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to use is `OuterClass.this.methodName();`

For example if the outer class is `A` you need to call  `A.this.onClick();`

```
interface IOnClick {
    public void onClick();
}

class A {
    public void onClick(){
    }

    public void test(){
        IOnClick ic = new IOnClick(){
            public void onClick(){
                A.this.onClick();
            }
        };
    }
}
```